# Used dijit css in two pages, but working in first page only, in second page getting blank page

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, dijit.form

I have used dijit css for dijit/horizontalSlider in two pages , slider is getting loaded in first page but in second page getting blank. dojoz/data/DataGrid also loaded correctly in first page, but in second page getting blank.

UPDATED:

I have two buttons in home.html(parent page) and calling  django templates grid.html and move.html. Here is grid.html source code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
    <head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'pmda_app/dojo/../dijit/themes/claro/claro.css' %}">
    <style>
    @import "{% static 'pmda_app/dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/claro/EnhancedGrid.css' %}";
    @import "{% static 'pmda_app/dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/EnhancedGrid_rtl.css' %}"
    <script src="{% static 'pmda_app/dojo/dojo.js' %}"></script>
    <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
    <script>
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid");
    dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Pagination");

    dojo.ready(function(){
    /*set up data store*/
    var data = {
      identifier: 'id',
      items: []
    };
    var data_list = [
       { col1: "normal", col2: false, col3: 'But are not followed by two hexadecimal', col4: 29.91},
       { col1: "important", col2: false, col3: 'Because a % sign always indicates', col4: 9.33},
       { col1: "important", col2: false, col3: 'Signs can be selectively', col4: 19.34}
    ];
    var rows = 60;
    for(var i=0, l=data_list.length; i<rows; i++){
       data.items.push(dojo.mixin({ id: i+1 }, data_list[i%l]));
    }
    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});

    /*set up layout*/
    var layout = [[
       {'name': 'Column 1', 'field': 'id'},
       {'name': 'Column 2', 'field': 'col2'},
       {'name': 'Column 3', 'field': 'col3', 'width': '230px'},
       {'name': 'Column 4', 'field': 'col4', 'width': '230px'}
    ]];

    /*create a new grid:*/
    var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
     id: 'grid',
     store: store,
     structure: layout,
     rowSelector: '20px',
     }},
    document.createElement('div')
     );

    /*append the new grid to the div*/
    dojo.byId("gridDiv").appendChild(grid.domNode);

    /*Call startup() to render the grid*/
    grid.startup();
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
     <div id="gridDiv"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Here is the move.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <title>Scaling, scrolling, and panning.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'pmda_app/dijit/tests/css/dijitTests.css' %}"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'pmda_app/dojo/../dijit/themes/claro/claro.css' %}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'pmda_app/dojo/dojo.js' %}" data-dojo-config="isDebug: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
    <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dijit.form.HorizontalSlider");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.HorizontalRule");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.HorizontalRuleLabels");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
    dojo.require("dojo.parser"); // scan page for widgets
    dojo.require("dojox.charting.Chart");
    dojo.require("dojox.charting.axis2d.Default");
    dojo.require("dojox.charting.plot2d.Areas");
    dojo.require("dojox.charting.plot2d.Lines");
    dojo.require("dojox.charting.action2d.MouseZoomAndPan");
    dojo.require("dojox.charting.plot2d.Grid");
    dojo.require("dojox.charting.action2d.Tooltip");
    dojo.require("dojox.charting.themes.PlotKit.orange");

    makeObjects = function(){
    var data = [4,8,2,1,6,4,8,8,2,1,6,4,9,0,2,8,9,3,4,1,2,1,6,9,1,0,8,2,4,6,1,6,4,8,2,1,6,4,8,2,1,6,4,8,2,1,6,4,8,2,1,6,4,8,2,1,6,4,8,2,1];
    var dates = [2013-11-19,2013-11-20,2013-11-21,2013-11-22,2013-11-25];
    chart = new dojox.charting.Chart("test");
    chart.setTheme(dojox.charting.themes.PlotKit.orange);
            chart.addAxis("x", {
                    labels: dojo.map(dates, function(value, index){
                        return {value: index + 1, text: value};    }), minorTicks:false, stroke: "green"
                    })              
            .addAxis("y", {vertical: true, fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major", minorTicks:false, stroke: "green", min: 0})
            .addSeries("UsersGraph", data,{stroke: {color: "blue", width: 1}}, {fill: "green"});
          chart.addPlot("default", {type: dojox.charting.plot2d.Lines, gap: 5});

            chart.addPlot("grid", {type: dojox.charting.plot2d.Grid, hMinorLines: true});
            new dojox.charting.action2d.Tooltip(chart, "default");
            chart.render();

     };

     dojo.addOnLoad(makeObjects);

     </script>
    </head>
    <body class="tundra">
    <div id="test" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; margin: 30px auto 0px auto;">  </div>
    <table>
    <tr><td align="center" class="pad">ZOOM X(<span id="scaleXValue">1</span>)</td></tr>
    <tr><td>
            <div id="scaleXSlider" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/HorizontalSlider" class="clearfix" value="1" minimum="1" maximum="5" discreteValues="6" showButtons="false" style="width: 500px;">
                    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/HorizontalRule" container="bottomDecoration" count="5" style="height:5px;"></div>
                    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/HorizontalRuleLabels" container="bottomDecoration" minimum="1" maximum="5" count="5"    constraints="{pattern: '##'}" style="height:1.2em;font-size:75%;color:gray;"></div>
            </div>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td align="center" class="pad">PAN X (<span id="offsetXValue">0</span>)</td></tr>
    <tr><td>
            <div id="offsetXSlider" dojoType="dijit.form.HorizontalSlider" 
                            value="1" minimum="0" maximum="1000" discreteValues="1001" showButtons="false"
                            style="width: 500px;">
            </div>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

First I have clicked on grid.html and it displayed the data correctly, after that clicked on move.html for chart with horizontal sliders, chart came properly but no sliders are there. 
If I clicked move.html first time it is wokring fine(getting chart and sliders also)

Comment: Provide an error message, some source code, etc.

Comment: For the 1st time all static files are loading(css/js/gif) but second time files are not getting loaded. Please check this link for addition info "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432605/dijit-form-horizontalslider-is-getting-loaded-for-first-time-only"

Comment: Added source code in the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [DOJO and DIJIT can not parse same ID twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15889588):

> Dojo keeps track of the objects / widgets it creates by the specified id. If you run the parser again on an object with the same id, dojo tries to create a second instance, but there is already one, so it should throw an error in your js console.

Destroy the created widget/object ids before you parse the same page again. Here I have  declared 'widgets' as global variable, so that if any widgets ids are there just destroying them before parsing.

```
    if(widgets){
        widgets.forEach(function(widget) {
        widget.destroyRecursive();
    });
    }
    widgets =  dojo.parser.parse();
```

It's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your resources are correct? I mean, if you open a second html-page you must load the resources for this side again.

**UPDATE 1**

My guess would be, because you still want to use the widgets from the first Page, to write new ones for the second Page. You can't unregister them, because if you do, you can't use them anymore in the first Page.

So, the easiest Way is to write new ones for the second Page. The values from the first Page, can be transfered to the second.

**Update 2**

Last try :

1. Setup html pages
2. Write javascript seperatly and load it at the start like

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="...from/here/to/mygauge.js"</script>
   ```

Regards

Comment: Maintaining buttons for navigation,I'm loading same css/js files in both pages. suppose if I click on second button for the first time it's working fine but first page is not getting loaded and if I click on first button for the first time it's working fine but second page is not getting loaded(double click also dont work). using Jquery for event handling.

Comment: Please check this for additional info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432605/dijit-form-horizontalslider-is-getting-loaded-for-first-time-only

Comment: So, when i get you right, you use the same Widget you load once a second time? Maybe the error occurs, because the widgets are still registred. Are there any Errors in your console.log?

Comment: Yes, I'm using same Widgets in both pages. Yes, Maybe the Widgets are still registered and Please refer the above Log which I mentioned in the question itself. Please give me some work around if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]I make a fiddle out of your Code and it seems to be working well.

Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/E2J4A/

```
makeObjects = function () {
  var data = [4, 8, 2, 1, 6,...
```

Regards

Comment: I have integrated your sample code in my project and added the screen shot of result, problem is same.

Comment: still I'm facing the same problem, any one can help!

Comment: Sorry, ran out of ideas. Have you try to setup the gauge in a seperate js-file and load it at the start? Then you can asure that all code needed is loaded - include all definitions you made in.

Comment: Also it's possible that the gauge is loaded, but not the styling for the backround. Make sure that this definitions are loaded again with the gauge - not just the basic gauge without styling